# Manually turn RGB image into Grayscale Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let me preface this by saying, I understand there are functions that would do this for me, but I wanted to do it manually so I could understand what exactly is happening here.

So my goal is to read in a RGB image and turn it into a grayscale. All of my image processing work up to this point has been solely grayscale based, so I am a little bit lost.

I have tried to first read in the image by doing

```
fid = fopen('color.raw');
myimage = imread(fid, [512 384], 'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

but myimage ends up as an empty 0 x 0 matrix. I think I need to assign an "R" "G" and "B" value to each pixel, thus giving each pixel three values for the three colors, but I am not sure if thats correct, and even how to attempt that.

my question is the following: How would I read in a RGB image and then turn into a grayscale one.

EDIT: So I understand how I would go about turning the RGB into the grayscale after getting the R G and B values, but I cannot seem to make Matlab read in the image, can anyone offer any assistance? using imread seems to make the most sense, but

```
[pathname] = ...
     uigetfile({'*.raw';'*.mdl';'*.mat';'*.*'},'File Selector');
fid = fopen(pathname);
myimage = imread(fid);
fclose(fid);
```

Is not working, im getting an error of invalid filename for fopen, and I really do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually you just average the red, green, and blue components and then providing that average as the output for the red, green, and blue components. You can do this using a simple arithmetic mean

- (r+g+b)/3.

Or for kicks, you can use a geometric mean to get a slightly different contrast..

- (r*g*b)^(1/3).

Comment: Good point @LastCoder! You'll especially want to use luminosity when concerned with edge detection or areas where you need a human-like perception of contrast.

Comment: hey Paul_R and @LastCoder I am now outputting the 4 images (R G B , and the average) but the average is not grayscale, rather it is similar to green but with less red. the picture is intuitively what i would consider to be the average of the previous 3, as the colors are less extreme everywhere, but the image isnt in grayscale like i would like it to be. Any tips as to whats happening?

Comment: Given that a color is made up of a red, green and blue component: We take `average = (red+green+blue)/3` from that point - you now create a new color for the exported image. this new color will contain the following components: `red = average`, `green = average`, and `blue = average`. You don't need to make 4 images, just average the components of each pixel before you output. And yes, Shaun314 is correct that a weighted average will produce more realistic contrast. I'm a little confused what you're actually doing. The exported image should have a == g == b, and so will have no hue at all.

Comment: If your averaged image is still in color, maybe you are mapping the grayscale values to a color. Be sure to use the `colormap gray` command. There may be parenthesis around gray, I haven't used matlab in a while

Comment: If you give MATLAB a 2-d matrix, with no weird colormap things going on, it will never return something that actually has color in it. Does it actually have a green hue, or does the average image just almost match what the green values are? I would expect it to be the latter, which if you look at the luminosity equation, makes perfect sense as to why the green slice looks similar to the average slice.

Answer (score 3):

imread - read image from graphics file (it's in the documentation)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

For RGB to gray scale use the luminosity method. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

> The luminosity method is a more sophisticated version of the average
>   method. It also averages the values, but it forms a weighted average
>   to account for human perception. We’re more sensitive to green than
>   other colors, so green is weighted most heavily. The formula for
>   luminosity is 0.21 R + 0.71 G + 0.07 B.

Comment: using the following code 
`fid = fopen('color.raw'); 
myimage = imread(fid, [512 384], '*uint16');
fclose(fid);` Returns an error of "invalid filename" but color.raw is the correct name, and it is in the matlab folder. Do you happen to know why that is

Comment: @user2475404 - The documentation for imread requires a file name as the first parameter, but I suspect your problem is with the RAW format. Your fread command should of worked but perhaps your RAW file has header bytes that are causing the failure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with averaging all 3 values as other users have indicated is that that is not how our eyes work at all.

When you average your images, you get the result below (on the built in peppers.png image)

[image]

You are effectively doing grayImg=.33*R+.33*G+.33*B when you find the average, now compare that to how MATLAB calculates grayscale values (with consideration into how humans view images)

0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B

See the stark contrast in values?

To get better looking data, stay closer to the coefficients MATLAB uses :)

The way MATLAB renders it is like this:

[image]

Comment: Shaun, I'm surprised the difference is so drastic. Likely because the original has very primary-associated colors?

Comment: I was also surprised to be honest! The image itself is very primary associated though, many reds and greens (think peppers haha) which I think is the reason for that. I am guessing the OP has a similar issue with their image.